# When updating laravel I get Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/view, laravel/framework. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/view

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, illuminate

I am trying to update Larvel to v7.0 using composer update, but I'm getting that Laravel and immulinate view cannot co-exist. I've tried various version combinations, yet get the same error. How do I handle this? I'm running on CentOS 8, with PHP 7.2.24. This is the result of my update:

```
    - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle ~6.29.3 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v6.29.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
        ...
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.28.4 (conflict analysis result)
   
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.29.3 requires illuminate/view 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.0.0, ..., v5.3.23].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/view[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36], laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.4]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/view and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^7 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.4].
```

I'm trying to upgrade an inherited site and the requirements in composer.json are needed for the site functionality, so I'm trying not to change those too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade the version of [laravel-databases-oracle](https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle#v9.0.0) to at least version 9.0. That's the first time that support for illuminate/view bumped to: 5.8.*

Requirements:

```
php: ^7.1.3
illuminate/database: 5.8.*
illuminate/filesystem: 5.8.*
illuminate/http: 5.8.*
illuminate/support: 5.8.*
illuminate/view: 5.8.*
```